# Typescript - Missing initializer in const declaration

Tags: typescript, syntax, constants

I have below code. Getting error SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration

```
const manufacturers: any[] = [];        
console.log('Available Products are: ');
for (const item of manufacturers) {
     console.log(item.id);
}
```

if I change declaration to `const manufacturers= [];` 
code works fine, but VSCode shows warning 
"Variable 'manufacturers' implicitly has type 'any[]' in some locations where its type cannot be determined.

I am using node js v12.16.1 and typescript : ^2.5.3

Comment: Can't reproduce this error on TypeScript versions going back as far as 2.4.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare an interface for `manufacturers`, as TypeScript won't be able infer the properties for typechecking if you use `any`:

```
interface Manufacturer {
  id: string;
  // add other properties
}

const manufacturers: Manufacturer[] = [];
```

Comment: Why need to declare interface ? I need an array of type Any.  const manufacturers: any[] = [ {id =101 , name = 'test 1'}, {id =102 , name = 'test 2'}];

Comment: Either you use an interface, or you declare it with any. I highly recommend interface because TypeScript needs it for typechecking.

Comment: @RajeshreeNevare hey, did my answer solve your issue?

Comment: Yes, Declaring interface will work. But any is not working. I have suppressed strict type checking from tsconfig.json file

Comment: Yeahh good call. You should limit the use of `any` due to my above point